# Burst camera without button

Tags: android

I created a burst camera and i want that when the activity starts, the camera starts taking pictures automatically without pressing any button.

It says: Unfortunately, FrontVerify has stopped when i try to put:

> preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
>                               jpegCallback);

on the onCreate method.

The thing is: I want to create a series of photos ta simulate a button. When the user put the finger near the camera and it stays all black, i have the algorithm that tells me that BLACK = TRUE, so move on to the next activity. Therefore i don't need any physical or digital button, i could use the camera for that issue.

So the only way so far i made it work so far was with the onClick method and
i really want to get rid of the onClick method that is here:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                            jpegCallback);
                    buttonClick.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

And the algorithm for the burst camera is this one:

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
                // outStream =
                // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
                // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
                // Or write to sdcard
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                        "/sdcard/eyeverify/still%d.jpg",
                        System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
            try {
                stillCount++;
                camera.startPreview();
                if (stillCount < 10) {
                    preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                            jpegCallback);
                } else {
                    stillCount = 0;
                    buttonClick.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error starting preview: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

}
```

So i cant figure it out, how to start the App and the camera start bursting automatically.

Comment: So right now you have a button that performs it but you want it to do it right when you start your app, why dont you just put that code in the onCreate() method?

Comment: Cant understand, you dont want the button but still say you need the button, why exactly wont work if you put it on onCreate?

Comment: It says: Unfortunately, FrontVerify has stopped

And i dont wan the button at all.

Comment: If it crash post the logcat output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    yourBtn.performClick();
  }
}, 1000).
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this in your OnStart or you OnCreate:

```
preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                        jpegCallback);
```

Depending on how you want to manage your app on OnPause and OnResume it may be better to put it into OnResume. If you want it to start with the camera burst whenever paused, or just when first launched.

I would also ensure you clean up your resources in OnStop.